# Still old configurations after updating CyanogenMod

Tags: cyanogenmod

I installed CyanogenMod 13 (UNOFFICIAL-20160104-NIGHTLY) on my Sony Xperia M (nicki) and updated it to CyanogenMod 13 (stable-20160527-NIGHTLY) successfuly. The update had no change on the configurations like the wallpaper, applications menu style, notifications menu, etc.
I installed the exact version (CyanogenMod 13 (stable-20160527-NIGHTLY)) on my wife's Sony Xperia M (nicki) last day but I saw the wallpaper, applications menu style, notifications menu and some other things are changed.

In our Linux desktop (like Fedora, Ubuntu, etc.) usually there is a `.config` directory in the `~home` that keeps the configuration and if you simply delete this directory, after starting the application, it will run with new default configurations.

How can I delete/change old just CyanogenMod configurations/preferences directory on my CyanogedMod to see the new face and new menus of CyanogenMod? (I have no special customize on CyanogenMod but I do not to wipe all of my data on the internal storage like applications, etc.1)

Comment: I think you did a dirty flash to have a fresh install. Wipe through recovery and then install fresg

Answer (score 0):

Did you first wipe the /system partition before you flashed the rom?
Chances are you didn't. You may want to reflash the rom preferrably after wiping /system and /data

Comment: For first install of CyanogenMod (CyanogenMod 13 (stable-20160527-NIGHTLY)) I did, but I upgraded it to CyanogenMod stable-20160527-NIGHTLY via cmupdater and did not wiped the data. I do not want to wipe data anymore, just configurations/preferences .